# Proving Mean Value Theorem by halving technique

Tags: real-analysis

The goal of this question is to provide a practical way to approximate the point $c$ in the Mean Value Theorem.

Assume that $f$ is a continuous function which is defined on the interval $[a,b]$ and $v$ is an arbitrarily chosen number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

(i) Explain that why is that sufficient just to consider the case in which $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have different signs and also, $v=0$.

(ii) Assume that $m$ is on the middle of $[a,b]$ . Prove that if $f(m) \neq 0$ , then $f(a)f(m) \lt 0$ or $f(b)f(m) \lt 0$ . So, We can halve the length of the interval which $c$ is in it.

(iii)  By repeating the process you started in the part (ii), Prove that there exists a nested sequence of closed intervals like $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ such that for each $n$, $f(a_n)f(b_n) \lt 0$ and  $b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}=\frac{b_n-a_n}{2}$.

(iv) Assume that $c$ is a unique point such that each $[a_n,b_n]$ has $c$.  Prove that $f(c)=0$.

(v) Find an equation for $b_n-a_n$ in terms of $a,b,n$.  Then, By using it, find an approximation  ( greater than ) $|\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}-c|$.

My try :

About part (i) (Thanks to ArnaudD.)  ( EDITED )
If $f(a)f(b)>0$ then we define $g(x)=f(x)-v$ So $g(a)=f(a)-v$ and $g(b)=f(b)-v$ . Since $v$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, So clearly $g(a)g(b)<0$ and $g(v)=0$ ( Which is again the first case )

About part (ii), If $f(m) \neq 0$, then it is either greater than or less than zero. So, The fact that $f(a)f(m) \lt 0$ or $f(b)f(m) \lt 0$ is obvious. What i don't understand is what question means by halving the interval.  Does it mean $[a,m]$ and $[m,b]$ ? How is this useful?

Note 2 : The question is so long ... i'm completely confused  ... i have no idea about the parts (iii) to (iv)...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution for (i) is a bit unclear to me. What happens if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have the same sign? You need to prove that the "reduced" case is also enough to cover this situation.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I somehow imagined that $f$ is a part of another function in that case ... maybe my idea is wrong ... i said i'm confused

Comment: What if $f(a)=f(b)$?

Comment: I can give you a hint for (i) : consider the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(x)-v$. For your question about point (ii), yes, what is meant by "halving the interval" is that you can consider one of the intervals $[a,m]$ or $[m,b]$ (whose lengths are half the length of $[a,b]$; this is what you need for point (iii)).

Comment: @ArnaudD. I edited the text according to what you said :) Is it correct now ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea; but you can do this even if $f(a)f(b)\leq 0$. The point is just that up to a translation, you can choose where is your $v$.

Comment: I still don't get how you can pick different signs?

Comment: @copper.hat which part are you talking about ? If (i) , then according to what Arnaud said, the idea is just moving the graph of the function ...

Comment: If $f(a)=f(b)$ then $v=0$, I don't see how you can move $f$ so that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have different signs.

Comment: @copper.hat $v$ should be between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ ... so the case you're talking about is not valid :)  I mean there is no such $v$ ...

Comment: Sure there is, $v=f(a)$.

Comment: @copper.hat what i mean is that the theorem says "IF" $f(a) \lt v \lt f(b)$, then .... i mean the theorem just speaks about this kind of $v$.  So there is nothing to prove about the case that $v=f(a)$ or $v=f(b)$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous with $a<b$ and $f(a)<0<f(b).$

[1]..... Definitions.Let $I_1=[a,b]$ and  $e_1=(a+b)/2.$ When $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ and $e_n=(a_n+b_n)/2,$  define $I_{n+1}=[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ and define $e_{n+1}$ by

$\quad$(i) If $f(e_n)>0$ let $I_{n+1}=[a_n,e_n].$  If $f(e_n)<0$ let $I_{n+1}=[e_n,b_n].$ And  $\quad\; \; \; \; e_{n+1}=(a_{n+1}+b_{n+1})/2.$

$\quad$(ii). If $f(e_n)=0$ then $I_{n+1}=[e_n,e_n]=\{e_n\}$ and $e_{n+1}=e_n.$

[2]......Let $\{x\}=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}I_n.$  We have $x=\lim_{n\to \infty} e_n.$

We have $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(e_n).$ So if $f(e_n)\leq 0$ for infinitely  many $n$ and $f(e_n')\geq 0$ for infinitely many $n'$ then $f(x)=0.$ We show,by contradiction, that this must happen:

If $f(e_n)>0$ for all but finitely many $n,$ let $n^*$ be the least $n$ such that $\forall m\geq n\; (f(e_m)>0).$ Then $x=a_{n^*}\;$ [because $ e_n-a_{n^*}=2^{-(n-n^*)}(b_{n^*}-a_{n^*})$ for $n>n^*.]\;$ Therefore $$f(a_{n^*})=f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(e_n)\geq 0.$$ So $n^*\ne 1$ (because $f(a_1)<0$).  Therefore by def'n of $n^*$ we have $f(e_{n^*-1})<0.$

But then the def'n (i) of $I_{n^*}$ from $I_{n^*-1}$ implies $a_{n^*}=e_{n^*-1},$ giving $$f(x)=f(a_{n^*})=f(e_{n^*-1})<0,$$ contradicting  $f(x)\geq 0.$  By  a mirror-argument we also get a contradiction  if $f(e_n)< 0$ for all but finitely many $n.$

I think the classical proof is much clearer: There exists $d\in (0,b-a)$ such that $\forall x\in [a,a+d)\; (f(x)<0).$ Let $d_0=\sup \{d\in (0,b-a):\forall x\in [a,a+d)\;(f(x)<0) \}.$ It is easy to show that $f(x+d_0)=0.$